# How to Encode Json with Arrays Structure in PHP MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, decode

I have 2 tables in MySql

**Section**

```
ID       Name
=====================
1        Section1
2        Section2
```

**Category**

```
ID        SectionID     Name
=========================================
1           1           Category1
2           1           Category2
3           2           Category3
```

How can I decode JSON from PHP to get the result that looks like this:
{sections:[
{sectionName: "Section1", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category1"},{categoryName: "category2"}]},
{sectionName: "Section1", categoryList: [{categoryName: "category3"}]}
]}

This is what I have now:
$sql_section = "select * from section";
$sql_category = "select * from category";

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Exact same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982529/how-to-design-an-array-structure-and-encode-to-json-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean encode. You simply need to make an array with the same structure of the json that you want and then use $json = json_encode($my_array)